# htaccess line - 500 error

Tags: apache, .htaccess, apache2

I have a htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I want to add the line below, but it gives me 500 error.

Options -Indexes

Can somebody help?

Comment: Check the Apache's **error log** -- it will tell you the EXACT reason for the error (that's what error log is for).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if the directory where your .htaccess lives in has enabled the neccessary **AllowOverride** (enabled must be: AuthConfig and Options at least) in the httpd.conf.

Make sure it is not within the

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
...
</IfModule>
```

part of your .htaccess

Usually you should have a logging-message in your error-log. I assume, that you will find something like this:

```
[alert] [client 192.xxx.xxx.xxx] /path/to/web/.htaccess: Options not allowed here
```

This solution does not always help (depending on the apache-version you are using): In some cases you have to move this section to your httpd.conf to make it work.

It is explained in detail in the [apache-docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#allowoverride).

Comment: that SHOULDN'T cause a 500 error though - it should fail silently; the override just won't work - yes?

Comment: I saw this problem on some apache-versions, that it is not ignored, instead the unexpected internal error was thrown.

Comment: Oooh - I'll have to make a mental note of that for future reference - thanks :) Even if this answer doesn't resolve the original problem, it's still useful!

Comment: if the answer was helpfull and solved your problem, please mark the answer as accepted, so others see that this answer was correct.